# PHP - how to generate different timestamps in the loop?

Tags: php, timestamp, microtime

How can I loop an array and create different timestamp for each iteration?

```
$array = array(
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two'
);

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    var_dump( "CONTENT_" . round(microtime(true) * 1000));
}
```

Result:

```
string(21) "CONTENT_1470885495013"
string(21) "CONTENT_1470885495013"
```

They are the same, but I want them to be unique to each others. What have I missed?

**EDIT:**

```
var_dump( "CONTENT_" . time());
```

Even with `time()`. I get the identical results.

Comment: Because the execution of foreach complete within milliseconds.So you are getting same timestamp for every element

Comment: Why not use something fit-for-purpose instead ~ http://php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php... `var_dump(uniqid('CONTENT_'))`

Comment: If you want to build your logic around uniqueness of time - better stop and reconsider.

Comment: Try this `round(microtime() * rand() * 100))`

Comment: @Saurabh no no no no no no!